# PhraseMatcher does not match LEMMA

Tags: python, spacy

My goal is to PhraseMatcher works on both LEMMA and LOWER, since attr can be only one , I have done the following solution:

```
pharsematcher=PhraseMatcher(self._nlp.vocab, attr='LEMMA')
nlp.add_pipe(self._lower_case_lemmas, after="tagger")

def _lower_case_lemmas(self,doc) :
     for token in doc :
      if token.lemma_.lower() == "-pron-": ##This is to solve when lemma is --pron- and not the real word like (your,i)
          token.lemma_ = token.text.lower()
      else:              
        token.lemma_ = token.lemma_.lower()

     return doc

def _addPharseMatchRules():
        Referal_match_wrods=['your','ur']
        your_patern=[self._nlp(text.lower()) for text in Referal_match_wrods]
        self._pharsematcher.add('your', None, *your_patern)
```

The problem is that the PhraseMatcher does not match LEMMA:

for example : `'Doctor: what is your date of birth'

Tokenized correctly :

```
('Doctor:', 'doctor:', 'PROPN', 'NNP', 'npadvmod', 'Xxxxx:', False, False)
('what', 'what', 'PRON', 'WP', 'attr', 'xxxx', True, True)
('is', 'be', 'AUX', 'VBZ', 'ROOT', 'xx', True, True)
('your', 'your', 'DET', 'PRP$', 'poss', 'xxxx', True, True)
('date', 'date', 'NOUN', 'NN', 'attr', 'xxxx', True, False)
('of', 'of', 'ADP', 'IN', 'prep', 'xx', True, True)
('birth', 'birth', 'PROPN', 'NNP', 'pobj', 'xxxx', True, False)
```

But when looking on the matches:

```
       matches = (self.NlpObj).AssignDocToPharsMatcher()
       List_of_Matches=[]
       for match_id, start, end in matches:
        List_of_Matches.append(((self.NlpObj)._nlp.vocab).strings[match_id])  # Get string representation
```

I am getting no matches , while I was expecting to get 'your'.

How can I solve the issue?

Thanks,

Nir

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, When loading the pharsematcher, I should add the pipe prior to loading the pharsematcher

so instead of:

```
pharsematcher=PhraseMatcher(self._nlp.vocab, attr='LEMMA')
nlp.add_pipe(self._lower_case_lemmas, after="tagger")
```

I change it to:

```
nlp.add_pipe(self._lower_case_lemmas, after="tagger")    
pharsematcher=PhraseMatcher(self._nlp.vocab, attr='LEMMA')
```

That solved the problem.